# How to retrieve coordinates from a grid

Tags: python, matrix, grid, coordinates

I generated a grid of points using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N1=15
N2=10
x = np.arange(0, N1)
y = np.arange(0, N2)
T1, T2 = np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.scatter(T1,T2)
plt.grid()
```

i want to retrieve the 2-D coordinates from the points in the grid in a matrix form.

I tried to use a layout to get the coordinates

Comment: What shape do you want the matrix to be? (2, 150)?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you want a matrix with all the points coordinates, which you can achieve by doing: `[[*zip(a,b)] for a, b in zip(T1,T2)]`

Comment: If you use statements like "tried", people will be curious what you have tried. Try to add that code, even if it doesn't yield your result, so people have an idea of what you are working on